# Web.config from one site affecting another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, silverlight

I have two different sites in my development machine. One is a Silverlight + WCF + Ria services application, in VS 2015, while the other is a VS 2017 MVC Web Api application. They are totally unrelated, from different costumers of mine. they are in different application pools.

The problem is that when i access the Silverlight App I get a error message pointing to the MVC web.config:

```
The CodeDom provider type “Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider” could not be located
```

And it is pointing to the second project's web.config (line 80 is in red):

```
Line 78:   <system.codedom>
Line 79:     <compilers>
Line 80:       <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
Line 81:         type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
Line 82:         warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
```

When I access the second project directlyit works. I have to rename the second projects web.config file to another extension to be able to use the first.

Edit:
I found the problem. My "default WebSite" was pointing to my MVC Web Api Application, instead of inetpub\wwwroot. When I changed it back to wwwroot to problem was gone!

Comment: Are they both sharing the same IIS virtual host?

Comment: By Virtual Host you mean a virtual machine? They are not on a virtual machine, it's my development machine, IIS is installed on it, and they're both on my computer.

Comment: No, by Virtual Host I mean Virtual Host, meaning that you should create different applications (virtual hosts) for each application, then the web.configs will not affect each other.

Comment: Well, I created both from Visual Studio, with the "Create Virtual Directory" button in project config page. They're seems to be different application, because in none of them there is a "Convert to application" option, and the icon seems to indicate that too. They're also assigned to different application pools.